# Android File Path URL

Tags: android

I am trying to see if a file exists in my app, for reasons I wont go into I put the resource in this location:

MyAppFolder/src/assets/data/mymp3.mp3

But what should the file path be for:

```
String path = "??";
    File file = new File( path );
    if( file.exists() ) 
        message = "exists";
    else
        message = "does not exists";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html), your folder structure is not as recommended for Android. It should be

```
MyAppFolder/src
MyAppFolder/assets/..
```

And yes, use AssetManager.

Comment: I didn't even notice the /src/ in there. Keep assets out of /src/!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [AssetManager](http://d.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). If the file can't be opened, it doesn't exist. If it can be opened, use the InputStream you just got. Besides, if the file is in your project it'll exist.

Comment: AssetManager am = appContext.getAssets();
   am.open(fileName); but what should I put under file name? What is the path?

Comment: The path is relative to the /assets directory in your projects. e.g. /assets/audio/background.mp3 would be audio/background.mp3.